Why neither branch of if-statement is reached?
Since .value is true, which does not have an field message, I thought .message? should be evaluated to false. Then "Y" should be printed. Can you help me understand why neither "X" nor "Y" is printed?
$ jq '.value|if .message? then "X" else "Y" end' <<< '{"value":true}'

How to revise the code so that if "message" is a field of the value of .value, then print "X", otherwise print "Y"?

It's not evaluated to false. if (.message? // false) then … would work

true cannot have a key message, so .message? returns nothing, and neither branch is executed. See for example Why is jq modify and if-then-else not working
Instead, you can check to ensure that . is an object, as well as checking for the existence of the key, with if type == "object" and .message?. As shown below, this returns "X" only if the message key exists, and "y" if there is no message key, or if the value isn't an object.

$ jq '.value|if type == "object" and .message? then "X" else "Y" end' <<< '{"value":true}'
"Y"
$ jq '.value|if type == "object" and .message? then "X" else "Y" end' <<< '{"value":{"message": true}}'
"X"
$ jq '.value|if type == "object" and .message? then "X" else "Y" end' <<< '{"value":{"notmessage": true}}'
"Y"


type == "object" and .message? can be simplified by removing the ?

Use try/catch instead with --arg and getpath
JSON_SIMPLE='{"value":true}'
JSON_NESTED='{"value": {"message": true}}'
JSON_EXPR='(if (getpath($fields|split("."))? != null) then "X" else "Y" end) // "Y"'

echo '{"value":true}' | 
jq --arg fields value.message \
  '(if (getpath($fields|split("."))? != null) then "X" else "Y" end) // "Y"'

$ jq --arg fields value.message "$JSON_EXPR" <<<"$JSON_SIMPLE"
"Y"

$ jq --arg fields value.doesnotexist "$JSON_EXPR" <<<"$JSON_SIMPLE"
"Y"

$ jq --arg fields value.message "$JSON_EXPR" <<<"$JSON_NESTED"                        
"X"

$ jq --arg fields value.doesnotexist "$JSON_EXPR" <<<"$JSON_NESTED"
"Y"

